# Python: How to convert a list of integers into nested lists of integers where max-min for each nested list never exceeds X?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm actually having a hard time explaining this problem. The title ask for this:

```
limit = 100
l = [1, 2, 4, 9, 33, 77, 85, 100, 151, 304, 405, 407, 499]

do_something(l, limit)

[
[1,2,4,9,33,77,85,100],
[151],
[304],
[405, 407, 499]
]
```

But that was just one step in my thought process. Truth is, I need this result:

```
limit = 100
l = [1, 2, 4, 9, 33, 77, 85, 100, 151, 304, 405, 407, 499]

do_something(l, limit)

[
range(1,101),
range(151,152),
range(304,305),
range(405,500)
]
```

Notice range never exceeds the limit of 100, and its creating a list out of ints from `l` that fall within the limit (starting from `l[0]` and resetting any time limit is exceeded). I am brainstorming ideas over here, but everything I can think of iterates over my list several times. If that's necessary so be it, but I'd like to be a bit more efficient than that.

Thanks for any help

Comment: If you can do the first version, you can convert that to the second version by using `range(min(sublist), max(sublist)+1)`

Comment: And if the lists are sorted, you can use `sublist[0]` and `sublist[-1]+1` instead of min/max.

Comment: @Barmar Unfortunately, the first part is my problem. I only included the second part just in case anyone knows of a more efficient way of obtaining that end result.

Comment: Is each group supposed to be based on multiples of `limit`, e.g. `1-100`, `101-200`, etc.? Or do the limits start from the element that breaks out of each range, so it's `1-100`, `151-250`, `304-403`, `405-504`?

Comment: @Barmar, the element that breaks out of each range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the sorted list. Each time you start a group, save the first value of the range in one variable. Then as you step through the list, update the last value of the range to the current element. Whenever the element exceeds `first+limit`, you start a new range.

```
def do_something(l, limit):
    if l == []:
        return []
    end = l[0] + limit
    result = []
    first = last = l[0]
    for i in sorted(l):
        if i < end:
            last = i
        else:
            result.append(range(first, last + 1))
            first = last = i
            # reset the limit
            end = i + limit
    # append the last sublist
    result.append(range(first, last+1))
    return result
```

Comment: `do_something([0, 5], 5)` returns `[[0], [5]]`, even though the difference doesn't exceed 5.

Comment: I've been debugging it. Try now. It returns `[range(0, 1), range(5, 6)]`

Comment: Yes, now only the first issue remains.

Comment: Unclear whether it's supposed to be inclusive or exclusive. I assumed exclusive.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for your help. It is supposed to be exclusive. This functions with my data perfectly. Thank you

Comment: @MrChadMWood So you're saying 5 exceeds 5?

Comment: @KellyBundy `0 - 4` contains `5` values, `5` is outside that.

Comment: @Barmar That's not what *"max-min for each nested list never exceeds X"* means, and not what your own *"exceeds first+limit"* means, either.

Comment: @KellyBundy, I'm not sure what you're referring to. I did notice a discrepancy with this solution prior to it being edited. The last nested range was incorrect. In my test, the edited version of this answer solves that issue.

Comment: @Barmar can you explain `first = last = l[0]` to me? Ive never seen logic that uses two '=' on the same line beside checking if two objects are equal (thats '==' though). I would have thought that `first = last = l[0]` would result in an error.

Comment: It's just short for `first = l[0]` and `last = l[0]`. You're allowed to chain assignments.

Comment: For anyone arriving here in the future, this solution tested fastest with my sample data. `1.49 µs ± 18.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)`. Once I figure out how to, I'll accept this answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

you also can emplement such logic:

```
def do_something(l,limit):
    res = []
    x = y = 0
    for y in range(len(l)):
        if y==len(l)-1 or l[x] + limit <= l[y+1]:
            res.append(range(l[x], l[y]+1))
            x = y + 1
    return res

do_something(l,limit)

>>> out
'''
[range(1, 101), range(151, 152), range(304, 305), range(405, 500)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you try dictionaries to store list of values within limit.
In this implementation, list is not necessarily to be sorted.

```
limit = 100
ranged_list = {}
for col in l:
  lst = ranged_list.get((col-1) // limit, [])
  lst.append(col)
  ranged_list[(col-1) // limit] = lst

print(list(ranged_list.values()))

>>> [
[1, 2, 4, 9, 33, 77, 85,100], 
[151],
[304],
[405, 407, 499]]
```

Comment: `defaultdict` or `.setdefault()` would be a little more pythonic ways of doing this.

Comment: `100` is supposed to be in the first list, not the second.

Comment: First, pythonic way is just matter of taste and it is very subjective.  Second, I am pretty sure that pruning the parameters is very easy to handle.

Comment: @Barmar , fixed 100 (lol) . Not much to fix thou

Comment: See the OP's response to my question in comments. The sublists are not supposed to be based on `value // limit`, because the ranges reset dynamically based on the data.